# SQL Multiple joins - must be an easier way

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, join

I have a table called Grades that we store pupils grades into for each year and term they sit exams.  We then display this as an NCL, GCSE or Point grades.  To find the NCL/GCSE equivalent grade we do a lookup on a different table that maps points to the correct GCSE/NCL equivalent grade.

However, this means my query has numerous joins to return a matching GCSE/NCL grade for our table of grades, I'm sure there's got to be an easier way

The code I have is below:

```
SELECT        
    Grades.GradeID, Grades.PupilID, Grades.GradeType, Grades.KeyStage2, Grades.Y7T1, 
    Grades.Y7T2, Grades.Y7T3, Grades.Y8T1, Grades.Y8T2, Grades.Y8T3, Grades.Y9T1, Grades.Y9T2, 
    Grades.Y9T3, Grades.Y10T1, Grades.Y10T2, Grades.Y10T3, Grades.Y11T1, Grades.Y11T2, 
    Grades.Y11T3, GradesToPoints.GCSEGrade AS KS2, 
    GradesToPoints_Y7T2.GCSEGrade AS [Year7 Term2], 
    GradesToPoints_Y7T3.GCSEGrade AS [Year7 Term3], 
    GradesToPoints_Y7T1.GCSEGrade AS [Year7 Term1], 
    GradesToPoints_Y8T1.GCSEGrade AS [Year8 Term1], 
    GradesToPoints_Y8T2.GCSEGrade AS [Year8 Term2], 
    GradesToPoints_Y8T3.GCSEGrade AS [Year8 Term3], 
    GradesToPoints_Y9T1.GCSEGrade AS [Year9 Term1], 
    GradesToPoints_Y9T2.GCSEGrade AS [Year9 Term2], 
    GradesToPoints_Y9T3.GCSEGrade AS [Year9 Term3], 
    GradesToPoints_Y10T1.GCSEGrade AS [Year10 Term1], 
    GradesToPoints_Y10T2.GCSEGrade AS [Year10 Term2], 
    GradesToPoints_Y10T3.GCSEGrade AS [Year10 Term3], 
    GradesToPoints_Y11T1.GCSEGrade AS [Year11 Term1], 
    GradesToPoints_Y11T2.GCSEGrade AS [Year11 Term2], 
    GradesToPoints_Y11T3.GCSEGrade AS [Year11 Term3], Grades.Subject
FROM            
    Grades 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y11T3 ON Grades.Y11T3 = GradesToPoints_Y11T3.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y11T2 ON Grades.Y11T2 = GradesToPoints_Y11T2.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y11T1 ON Grades.Y11T1 = GradesToPoints_Y11T1.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y10T3 ON Grades.Y10T3 = GradesToPoints_Y10T3.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y10T2 ON Grades.Y10T2 = GradesToPoints_Y10T2.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y10T1 ON Grades.Y10T1 = GradesToPoints_Y10T1.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y9T3 ON Grades.Y9T3 = GradesToPoints_Y9T3.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y9T2 ON Grades.Y9T2 = GradesToPoints_Y9T2.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y8T3 ON Grades.Y8T3 = GradesToPoints_Y8T3.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y8T2 ON Grades.Y8T2 = GradesToPoints_Y8T2.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y8T1 ON Grades.Y8T1 = GradesToPoints_Y8T1.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y7T3 ON Grades.Y7T3 = GradesToPoints_Y7T3.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y7T2 ON Grades.Y7T2 = GradesToPoints_Y7T2.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y7T1 ON Grades.Y7T1 = GradesToPoints_Y7T1.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints ON Grades.KeyStage2 = GradesToPoints.Points 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    GradesToPoints AS GradesToPoints_Y9T1 ON Grades.Y9T1 = GradesToPoints_Y9T1.Points
WHERE        
    (Grades.PupilID = @PupilID) AND (Grades.Subject = @Subject)
```

Comment: To me that looks like a database design problem; could you not store year and term as columns in the one table along with the grades, rather than having so many tables? If you really have that many students, you can still use one table and partition it by year.

Comment: If you show sample data and desired output there's certainly someone who will help you get it normalized.

Comment: I need to keep the GradesToPoints table as a separate table as the GCSE/NCL grades can change for the equivalent points.  The points will always stay the same. For example 50 points may equal A+ one year, or A- the next year.

Comment: `unpivot` then `join` then `pivot` might help here.

Comment: Shannon, I think you might have the answer, although I've never used pivot or unpivot. please could you provide an example of how I can use this

Comment: One tiny thing that might help a lot is using **table aliases** to reduce the amount of repetition on the table names in the list of columns ....

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your data model is not properly normalized.

Your grades table seems to have 1 record for each student, with a column for each grade.

Instead, your grades table should have 1 record for each grade, with an extra column to denote the type of grade, Y7T1, Y7T2, etc. This also increases flexibility: you won't have to change the database structure when adding or removing certain grades.

Comment: I agree, it would have been better to normalise the database this way. Although we are now storing a lot of data in the database so don't really want to change the database, just query the data a better way

Comment: This is called technical debt. My advice is take a look and understand this term.